# E: Unable to locate package libblas3gf

Tags: apt, package-management

Trying to install some packages for rtklib on my ubuntu mate running on arm processor.  I'm getting

```
$ sudo apt-get install libblas3gf
.
.
E: Unable to locate package libblas3gf
```

How to install libblas3gf and liblapack3gf?  I am running odroid xu4 with ubuntu mate.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? `libblas3gf` is a transitional package and that too only in 14.04. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libblas3gf

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: You should look for a version of rktlib for 16.04, in that case. Those BLAS and LAPACK libraries are for older releases.